# What safety class are these OEM 650nm 5mW laser diodes?

Tags: laser-diode

I am looking for some information about this type of laser diode. There is no safety class specified (is this ok?) and are rated 650nm and 5mW power. Is the rating IIIa?

What is the difference with other laser diodes with the same specifications (650nm, 5mW) but with different more expensive price?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a datasheet or are these alibaba/ebay/amazon parts?

Comment: No there is no datasheet

Comment: Does it have a lens to create a small spot far-field? 5 mW continuous? Then probably IIIa. Have a similar-looking one that I regard an eye-hazard.

Comment: I would not trust the 5mW rating to be remotely accurate unless you've measured it with your driver.

Comment: why the question is voted that does not meet the sites guidelines? Aren't laser diodes part of electrical engineering?

Comment: As for the laser diode I bought it from my electronics parts supplier, I suppose it is a common part and I seek for some information because there is no info/ no datasheet besides the few bits I noted. Isn't useful to gather some info about this because potentially it could be dangerous and it may protect or help users on how to handle it.

Comment: @JohnAm, don't worry too much about one vote to close. Maybe re-word this as "I am using this laser in my system design and need to know how to determine the laser safety class of the system" to make it clearly a design question and not a how-to-use-a-part question. But really I think it's fine as is.

Comment: As @glen_geek says, the safety class of the system will depend on what optics you put in front of the laser, and what circuit you use to drive it. So more details on that might help you get a more useful answer.

Comment: Thanks @The Photon So if the module is used without optics and is driven with 5mW aka use a 5k resistor with a 5V power supply (what driver... its a diode) and point it to my eye its ok? Because I doubt. It won't pop or make any sybstantial damage but the retina is going to get some scratches perhaps permanent. The light or perhaps the infrared that is emited can be felt as disturbing. But I wonder aren't these modules common? Noone has experience with these and the knowledge to supply some info?

Comment: `Because I doubt` ... +1 for that ... with unknown components, if they can hurt you, always assume the worst, unless proven otherwise

Comment: Good chance it won't even lase with a 5k resistor. Whatever configuration you choose, don't assume it's eye safe until you measure it.

Comment: @JohnAm, I didn't say it would be safe in any particular configuration, I said its safety class would depend what kind of optics you put in front of it. If you put a diverging lens in front and keep people more than 30 cm away it might be safe, for example. Or at 650 nm it might be class 2 (not safe to stare at, but because it's visible and very bright you won't stare at it unless you're physically forced to).

Comment: @The Photon Now I understand. I have almost none experience with lasers so I need some time to get it. Do you think I should delete the question?